# node.exe runs whenever I launch git-bash.exe

Tags: git-bash

Whenever I run git-bash.exe, I get no cursor until I press Ctrl+C.

[image: git-bash.exe]

When I try to close the window, I get an error: an instance of node is running.

[image: error message]

Error text:

```
---------------------------
mintty
---------------------------
Processes are running in session:
╎ WPID   PID  COMMAND
╎ 14612  1430 "C:\Program Files\nodejs\no
Close anyway?
---------------------------
OK   Cancel   
---------------------------
```

Process running:

[image: node process]

I've tried reinstalling the program, I've looked in all the config and profile files I can find but don't see what could be causing this, and I've only started noticing it recently.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. Some sort of Angular CLI call in .bashrc (I think it was) was launching upon startup. For whatever reason it just seemed to stall git bash.